# Double for loop with incompatible values

Tags: r

I would like to implement the following for loop:

```
for (start in c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)){
for (to in c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)){

runif(100,start,to)

}
}
```

Of course this would only work then `start` is smaller or equal to `to`

Is there a way to run only the cases where this condition holds?

Note: this is a simplified situation please don't offer solutions that do away with the for loop.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm generating 100 numbers from a uniform distribution with min=start and max=to. I would like to generate all possible combinations but of course I can't generate when min is larger than max so I would like to somehow specify a for loop which only runs it for those values where start>=to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand what you want to do and why you really want to use `for` loops, but :

```
for (start in c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)){
    for (to in ((start+1):10)){
        runif(100,start,to)
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
for (start in c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)){
  for (to in c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)){
    if( start < to ){ runif(100,start,to)}

  }
}
```

Not much is going to happen since you are not printing or assigning that result to anything, but at least you won't get a warning message now.

```
rnum<-numeric(0)
for (start in c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)){
  for (to in c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)){
    rnum <- c(rnum, if( start < to ){ runif(5,start,to)} )
   }
 }
 str(rnum)
# num [1:225] 1.6 1 1.57 1.75 1.11 ...
 sum(is.na(rnum))
#[1] 0
```

Another way would be to just make the inner loop indexes begin at the next integer greater than `start` (and skip the test):

```
rnum<-numeric(0)
for (start in c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)){
    for (to in (start+1):10){
        rnum <- c(rnum,  runif(5,start,to) )
    }
  }
str(rnum)
sum(is.na(rnum))
```

Comment: this would be good, but what happens when the condition is not satisfied, can I add some breakpoint so that it omits those loops where it is not satisfied?

Comment: It's not needed. When the conditions is not satisfied the consequent clause is ignored.

Comment: right but further parts of the code need the results from the random number generation

Comment: If you do not produce code that captures the complexity of the problem then how can we hope to address it?

Answer (score 0):

change the middle line:

```
 if(to>start)runif(100,start,to)
```

Comment: Note: this is a simplified situation please don't offer solutions that do away with the for loop.

Comment: ok, but if the condition is not satisfied it won't be able to generate the numbers and the rest of the code depends on the numbers, so I somehow need to omit those loops where the condition is not satisfied

Comment: The loop still runs, it just doesn't do whatever code is qualified by the if statement. subsequent lines will still run. What else are you trying to do in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

If your possible start and end values are actually equal (as in your example), you could use `combn`:

```
#using a loop
start_to <- combn(1:10,2)
n <- 2
set.seed(42)
randoms <- sapply(as.data.frame(start_to), function(x) runif(n, 
                                                             min=x[1], max=x[2]))

#without a loop
set.seed(42)
randoms2 <- matrix(runif(n*ncol(start_to), 
                           min=rep(start_to[1,], each=n), 
                           max=rep(start_to[2,], each=n)),
                   nrow=n)
```